# Do I need to manage functions registered with signalR (through connection.on )

Tags: callback, signalr

I'm using signalR to send some messages to the client.  I'm registering the client by using the `connection.on()` method:

```
function doStuff(){
...
}

        hub.on('doWork', doStuff);
```

later on:

```
hub.off('doWork', doStuff);
```

The code that registers the callback may be called multiple times throughout the user's session as they navigate.

When the user navigates away, will that de-register the callback or do I need to (somehow) manage that state myself and call `.off()`?

Comment: can you add more code , of how you register your client

Comment: I added some, but it's not much different than what I already had